# grep regex pattern causes unexpected command behavior

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, regex

I'm searching for lines with `$` and consecutively `'` or `"` through this grep in my terminal:

```
grep "\\$('|\")" -rin folder_path
```

After pressing enter the terminal doesn't think the line is complete so it adds another line for me to keep writing. If I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> while writing `folder_path` it shows this error:

```
bash: command substitution: line 107: syntax error: file premature end
bash: command substitution: line 106: unexpected file premature end while searching for `''
```

Those error messages were translated because a part of them are shown in portuguese. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```bsh
grep -rn "\$\('\|\"\)" /path/to/directory
```

Your problem is actually two-fold :

- From `grep`'s perspective, You are using the Extended Regex syntaces i.e. `(`, `|`, `)` without escaping them (to treat them special) inside your Basic Regex pattern. To overcome this either escape all those to treat them special or use the `-E` option of `grep`.
- Another problem caused by the above not escaping issue is that `$()` is the `bash` command substitution pattern, as you have not escaped the relevant characters `bash` was treating the pattern `$()` as command substitution. Note that the `\\$()` actually makes the command `\` plus command substitution as first `\` will make the second `\` literal and the remaining command substiturion pattern will be left as it is.

Also note that `-i` is needless here as we are not searching alphabatic characters. You might be interested in printing the file names :

```bsh
grep -Hrn "\$\('\|\"\)" /path/to/directory
```

Another thing is that you could get away without escaping `$` (indicates the end of line) in this case becasue there are characters to match after `$`, as a result `grep` will treat it literally :

```bsh
grep -Hrn "$\('\|\"\)" /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you're doing wrong, as I am not so good with grep, but you should be doing this  `grep  "\$'\|\$\""`, basically search for $' or $", and notice that those expressions are all escaped

Here's an example:

[image]